# Apollo-Client with subscriptions: failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

Tags: reactjs, graphql, nestjs, subscription, apollo-client

I have a reactjs application with `nestjs + graphql + subscription` server.

I have successfully setup graphql+subscriptions on the server. I can test it through the interactive playground interface. Everything works fine on server side.

Now I have been trying to setup graphql subscription on the client with no success. I have looked at countless tutorials and similar (or even same) github issues. Here is my client setup.

I don't know what I am doing wrong:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { getMainDefinition } from 'apollo-utilities';
import { split } from 'apollo-link';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { WebSocketLink } from 'apollo-link-ws';
import { IntrospectionFragmentMatcher, InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';


// this is a factory function I'm using to create a wrapper for the whole application

const ApolloProviderFactory = (props) => {

  const { graphQlUrl, introspectData } = props;

  const httpLink = new HttpLink({
    uri:`http://${graphQlUrl}`,
  });

  const wsLink = new WebSocketLink({
    uri: `ws://${graphQlUrl}`,
    options: {
      reconnect: true,
    },
  });

  const link = split(
    ({ query }) => {
      const definition = getMainDefinition(query);
      return (
        definition.kind === 'OperationDefinition'
        && definition.operation === 'subscription'
      );
    },
    wsLink,
    httpLink,
  );

  const fragmentMatcher = new IntrospectionFragmentMatcher({
    introspectionQueryResultData: introspectData,
  });
  const cache = new InMemoryCache({ fragmentMatcher });

  const client = new ApolloClient({
    link,
    cache,
  });

  // this component will wrap the whole application
  const ApolloWrapper = ({ children }: ApolloWrapperProps) => (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>{children}</ApolloProvider>
  );
  return ApolloWrapper;
}
```

Here is the error I'm getting when I run the app:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: port defined in props? compare request details with working one (playground)

Comment: Ok. I got it working. Following this post https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/3109, especially the last suggestion, I disabled the library `pace.js` and it is working as expected. 
Thank you for your help though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the `pace.js` library which was somehow interfering with the whole socket thing. After I disabled it, every thing works as expected.

Comment: where did you removed it? node_modules? I'm having the exact same error but did not found pace.js

Comment: pace.js was a small library I had installed (npm pace.js). So I just had to remove it. If you're not using it, then it is not in your node_modules or application in general